# how do I reset a paragraph in iText

Tags: java, pdf, itext

I'm creating a pdf in java using [iText](http://itextpdf.com)
Everything seems to we working the way I thought except when I use a loop, the paragraph I'm using seems to hold all data I store in it. to be a little bit more clear this is what I'm trying to do:

```
PdfPTable table = new PdfPTable();


for(int k=0; k < 3; k++){

Paragraph leftPar = new Paragraph();

leftPar.add(new Paragraph("\n List Object " + k, topicFont));

table_cell = new PdfPCell(leftPar)
table.addCell(table_cell);    
}
```

the output I want for my table is:

```
List Object 0
-------------
List Object 1
-------------
List Object 2
```

but the output I'm getting is:

```
List Object 0
-------------
List Object 0
List Object 1
-------------
List Object 0
List Object 1
List Object 2
-------------
```

I have to put the info in different cells, so My problem is I would think when I declare the leftpar = new paragraph it would create a new instance of it, but It seems to keep other stuff I added. I even tried leftPar = null; then leftpar = new paragraph and still nothing? any ideas?

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The answer was that the Table itself was keeping all other information on it. so I had to use the method flushContent();  at the end of the loop, after adding the table to the document.

```
table.flushContent();
```

Answer (score 1):

Try something like is mentioned [here](http://api.itextpdf.com/itext/com/itextpdf/text/Paragraph.html):

```
Paragraph p = new Paragraph("This is a paragraph",
               FontFactory.getFont(FontFactory.HELVETICA, 18, Font.BOLDITALIC, new Color(0, 0, 255)));
```

In your case maybe this would do:

```
Paragraph leftPar = new Paragraph("\n List Object " + k, topicFont);
```

Comment: It doesn't seem to work for me. the paragraph I have to add it to a cell so I can add it to my Table.

Comment: Ok I got it, it wasn't the paragraph at all, it was actually the Table which was keeping the info in it. so I had to do table.flushContent(); at the end of the for loop. Thanks!

Comment: Cool - maybe you can add a separate answer to show what really fixed you problem; i think that might help others as well